# How to create and populate Acces database using ADOX methods in c#

Tags: c#, ms-access, adodb

I want to create and populate an Access Database with ADOX in c#.

I'm able to create db and tables but how can I populate for example a column with values for example list of strings?

'''

```
{
CatalogClass accessDB = new CatalogClass();
string tmpStr;
string filename = @"C:\PsAUTO.accdb";
tmpStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;";
tmpStr += "Data Source=" + filename + ";Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=5";

accessDB.Create(tmpStr);

Table nTable = new Table(); 
nTable.Name = "MyTable";
nTable.Columns.Append("MyColumn", ADOX.DataTypeEnum.adVarWChar);

List<string> MyList = new List<string> { "One", "Two", "Three" };

// NOW HOW CAN I PUT VALUES IN MyList IN THE MyColumn????

accessDB.Tables.Append(nTable);
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(nTable);

// RELEASE THE RESOURCES
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(accessDB.Tables);
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(accessDB.ActiveConnection);
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(accessDB);
```

}
'''

Comment: Eh, there are plenty of tutorials of how to insert data into tables (using ADO/ADO.NET, not ADOX since ADOX is about inspecting/modifying database structure, not database content). You can't do it before the table has been appended to the database, though.

Comment: May I suggest that, once you create the database you use ADODB and plain SQL to create tables, columns, insert/update data?

Comment: @tinazmu Yes I think that I will do in this way, thanks